# How to resolve issue related to java installing

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, selenium

> A jre or jdk must be available in order to run Eclipse. No java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
> c:\user\ashish\downloads\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe in your current PATH.

Comment: Sometimes it worthy to sped some time and read the how to. You must update the PATH

Comment: Have you added JAVA_HOME and added bin to PATH environment variable?

Comment: @LutzHorn not correct.  Eclipse does not need the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

See the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?#Find_the_JVM):

> If a JVM is installed in the eclipse/jre directory, Eclipse will use it; otherwise the launcher will consult the eclipse.ini file and the system path variable. Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
>
> To explicitly specify a JVM of your choice, you can use the -vm command line argument

Comment: And how will that help with installing Eclipse? Do you have proof it uses the JAVA_HOME variable? It certainly has no effect on my environment.

Answer (score 2):

Unless explicitly told Eclipse just uses the default Java installation on the system, and does not go looking for other Java installations.  For Windows it is the one which copies java.exe into the Windows system folder.

The simplest way to get that is to go to http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp and install what is suggested until the website informs you you have Java.

(If Eclipse still does not want to start, be certain that you have the same 32bit/64bit version as was installed above)

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things in order to get rid of this problem:

**First:** You can refer to your `JDK` installation in `eclipse.ini` configuration file, as descriped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590).

**Second:** copy the `JRE` directory into you eclipse Home directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problems could be
1. JDK for 32 or 64 bit processors - I had a 64 bit processor but my eclipse was looking for 32 bit compatible java 
2. I downloaded 32 - bit processor and then updated eclipse.ini file

Hence, it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might have downloaded the wrong file i.e maybe 32 bit for a 64 bit OS (download 64 bit .exe file), try checking that, saves a lot of time.